# Extra whitespace around graphics when using PlotTheme -> Scientific

Tags: plotting, graphics, front-end

Sometimes when I use `PlotTheme -> "Scientific"` I get a bunch of extra whitespace on the output of the graphics. For example, with this code there is a large gap of white space between the graphic and the next cell of the notebook. If I use the default theme it goes away. Is there a way to fix this, so I can use the scientific theme without the extra white space?

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[
    x^2 + y^2 < 5,
    {x, -5.0, 10.0},
    {y, 0.7, 2.75},
    PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
  ],
 Plot[
    2 Cos[x],
    {x, -4, 10}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem when I use `AxesStyle` with `Plot`. My Mathematica version: 13.1.

Comment: @E.Chan-López good to know it is not just me. For some plots this can become very disruptive.

Comment: No such white gap in v13.1 Linux (Manjaro) or v13.1 Win 11.

Comment: I don't see a gap between this graphic and the next cell. I am using v12.2.0-Win7-x64.